# From 3D to 2D in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ipython

I would like to have this code:

```
chains3D = [[] for k in range(colors)]
        def addr(x,y,z): return x + (nx) * (y + (ny) * (z))
        for x in range(nx):
            for y in range(ny):
                for z in range(nz):
                    if (image[x,y,z] == background):
                        chains3D[1].append(addr(x,y,z))
                    else:
                        chains3D[0].append(addr(x,y,z))
```

in something like this:

```
chains2D = [[] for k in range(colors)]
        def addr(x,y): return x + (nx) * y 
        for x in range(nx):
            for y in range(ny):
                    if (image[x,y,0] == background):
                        chains2D[1].append(addr(x,y))
                    else:
                        chains2D[0].append(addr(x,y))
```

Ok I've solved the code issue, but now I've this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-6a7d44bd72b7> in <module>()
213                         objectBoundaryChain = larBoundaryChain(partial_3,chains2D[1])
214                         b2cells = csrChainToCellList(objectBoundaryChain)
--> 215                         sup_cell_boundary = MKPOLS((V,[FV[f] for f in b2cells]))
216 
217                         # remove the (local) boundary (shared with the piece boundary)     from the quotient cell

/Users/Fabio/larpy/lar.pyc in MKPOLS(model)
101     """
102     V, FV = model
--> 103     pols = [MKPOL([[V[v] for v in f],[range(1,len(f)+1)], None]) for f in FV]
104     return pols
105 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know why f is equals to the last number of b2cells, instead of the first,  but maybe this is not the real problem that produce this error

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried? What do you expect?

Comment: Who upvoted this...the problem isn't stated, there's no meaningful title, the code won't run by itself so as to be self-evident (`NameError`s all over...)

Comment: the problem is that I need to convert all the code from 3D to 2D and that version doesn't work because I need to access at every element of the image array but isn't possible.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-92c0d53d87b0> in <module>()
    198                         for x in range(nx):
    199                                 for y in range(ny):
--> 200                                                 if (image[x,y] == background):
    201                                                         chains2D[1].append(addr(x,y))
    202                                                 else:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: In the 3D version, image[x,y,z] are some numeric values, in the 2D version is an array and i need to have  some values instead of the array

Comment: https://github.com/cvdlab/larpy

The ONLY two classes to modify are FEMTEC2013.py and PNG2STACKARRAY3D.py

Comment: From your backtrace, it appears `image` is still 3 dimensional. So either you need to fix that in code before this, or use a single slice from image, like `image[x,y,0] == background`.

Comment: NB: edit your original question and the traceback in there (wrapped in a code block), instead of putting it in a code block. It's hardly legible this way.

Comment: Sorry but i'm new ok StackOverflow and I don't know how do that

Comment: There should be a light-grey 'edit' link at the bottom-left of the question, just below the various tags (next to the 'share' link).

Comment: i think it's not possible to add this like a code block, cause the code block it's made only for question and not for comment

Comment: Edit it in your original question, as I said before. Done that for you now.

Comment: Yes, great: now you've removed the question! How are people even supposed to help you if all they see is an error message? You should have *added* the traceback to the question, which was exactly what I had done before you removed the complete question.

Comment: I'm sorry @Evert, I've fixed all and now it's possible to view the code and the traceback

Comment: I don't know why f = 2483, that is the last value of b2cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you're trying to do and what is not working, but something that seemed weird is that you transformed:

```
return x + (nx) * (y + (ny) * (z))
```

into:

```
return x + (nx) * (y + (ny))
```

Shouldn't it have been:

```
return x + (nx) * y
```

instead? Considering that nz doesn't appear in your 3D version, ny shouldn't appear in the 2D one.

Comment: the addr function return the "address" of every element of the 2D array, so I need to acces at every element of the image array, and if I remove ny isn't possible

Comment: I think Vorty is correct here: `x + nx*y` will access all elements. The `ny` you add introducse an offset (`nx*ny`); if that works, most of the arrays you work with are still 3 dimensional. You should slice those into your preferred 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @Evert I think that the bast way is to send to you all the code, if you have some time to analyze it...

Comment: Ok, addr now work well... but i've another error. I've posted it on the question